# Replace substring in string using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to replace substring in string.

**String is**
`/string/otherstring?query=d78f1dbee59de41245fbf3c82b72b859ab688e30`

**Substring**
`query=d78f1dbee59de41245fbf3c82b72b859ab688e30` I need to replace to `query=`

I want to replace it using regexp and then using `string.replace`. But I can't write the regexp.

```
/\/string\/otherstring?query=/.exec(
    '/string/otherstring?query=d78f1dbee59de41245fbf3c82b72b859ab688e30'
)
```

It's not working.

**P.S.** `d78f1dbee59de41245fbf3c82b72b859ab688e30` is sha1 hash

Comment: why do you need regex for this you can directly store this in string and you can replace using string.replace

Comment: you missed one \ near ?

Comment: `"/string/otherstring?query=yoursha1hash".replace(/query=yoursh1hash$/, "query=");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.replace` . You don't need to apply the `exec` function.

```
string.replace(/(\/string\/otherstring\?query=)[A-Za-z0-9]+/g, "$1")
```

**or**

Try this if you want to deal with only lowercase letters and numbers.

```
string.replace(/(\/string\/otherstring\?query=)[a-z\d]+/g, "$1")
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I want

Answer (score 0):

you could use like this in js

```
'/string/otherstring?query=d78f1dbee59de41245fbf3c82b72b859ab688e30'.replace(/.*query=/,'')
```

or

```
'/string/otherstring?query=d78f1dbee59de41245fbf3c82b72b859ab688e30'.replace(/\/string\/otherstring\?query=/,'')
```